# Cannot connect from local machine to mysql docker running on server (error 10061) - Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose

So  i have production server that i want to connect to with Mysql Workbench.

When i start application all runs fine, so i conenct to it via IP of the server and  credentials.

My docker-compose looks like this :

```
...
     workaround-mysql:
        container_name: workaround-mysql
        image: mysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: workaround
          MYSQL_USER: someuser
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepass
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassss
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: %
        ports:
          - "3308:3306"
        restart: always
....
```

So on my prod machine i run spring application, mysql, nginx.
When i try to connect via workbench this is the error i get :

[image]

Error 10061.

I dont understand what im doing wrong. I had no trouble when i was doing local testing. Workbench worked fine.

**Is there some additional settings i have to do ? And can i do these required settings via docker-compose?**

On my firewall, i have set accept connection to mysql port:
[image]

Oh and the additional note : I get that error right when i press connect on workbench, I dont even have prompt to enter password.

And docker compose up output for mysql part :

[image]

Comment: It looks like i dont have access form my local machine to somehow connect to thsi server, i need to set something that i can do that for my user, no idea what so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is just a typo, but you put 3308 as a port in your docker-compose file. So either fix that to 3306 or use 3308 when connecting.

Comment: Tried both,  either i get 10060 or 10061. Bud in the case of 3306 its 10061, in case of 3308 its llike timeout , it takes long time and then you get error 10060

Comment: Did you also opened your firewall on port 3308? Maybe check connection to those ports first with telnet or nmap to be sure.

Comment: I will open the 3308 and try , i will also try to show nmap output in updated answer

Comment: Yup, you saved me some serious time now, thanks so much , didnt tought it would be firewall port issue. Awesome, used 3308 opened port and restarted server now i manged to log in. You are beast.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sometimes it's the little things. But should have worked also with port 3306 if you had that before in your docker-compose file and open port in firewall.